# Am trying to deploy my django app on heroku using gcs google cloud storage

Tags: django, heroku, google-cloud-storage

Am trying to deploy my django app on heroku using gcs google cloud storage as my storage it can't find the json file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3eGw.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome, in order to facilitate answering your question and to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the route to the credentials file points to a directory in your personal computer.

When deploying to a server, the credentials file route should point to the route that the credentials file will have in the server